# Why do these two identical benchmarks have different results on the same browser but with two different platforms?

Tags: javascript, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I want to understand why these two equal benchmarks have different results on these two different platforms.

1. [Classcat, clsx, obj-str, vanilla JS on perf.link](https://perf.link/#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%3D)
2. [Classcat, clsx, obj-str, vanilla JS on measurethat](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/12271/1/classcat-clsx-obj-str-vanilla#latest_results_block)

In the first one `arr.filter(Boolean).join(" ")` is the fastest, in the second one is the slowest!

**Why?**

The code I'm using is this:

```js
import classcat from "https://unpkg.com/classcat?module"
import clsx from "https://unpkg.com/clsx?module"
import objstr from "https://unpkg.com/obj-str?module"

const obj = {
  one: true,
  abcd: Math.random() <= 0.5,
  efghijkl: Math.random() <= 0.5,
  mnopqrstuvwxyz: Math.random() <= 0.5,
  efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz: Math.random() <= 0.5,
  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz: Math.random() <= 0.5,
  abcd: Math.random() <= 0.5,
  efghijkl: Math.random() <= 0.5,
  mnopqrstuvwxyz: Math.random() <= 0.5,
  efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz: Math.random() <= 0.5,
  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz: Math.random() <= 0.5,
  two: false,
  three: true
}

const arr = [
  true && "one",
  Math.random() <= 0.5 && "abcd",
  Math.random() <= 0.5 && "efghijkl",
  Math.random() <= 0.5 && "mnopqrstuvwxyz",
  Math.random() <= 0.5 && "efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  Math.random() <= 0.5 && "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  Math.random() <= 0.5 && "abcd",
  Math.random() <= 0.5 && "efghijkl",
  Math.random() <= 0.5 && "mnopqrstuvwxyz",
  Math.random() <= 0.5 && "efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  Math.random() <= 0.5 && "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  false && "two",
  true && "three",
]
```

```js
classcat(arr)
classcat(obj)
clsx(arr)
clsx(obj)
objstr(obj)
arr.filter(Boolean).join(" ")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a prime sample why you can't trust js benchmarks.
The way the tests are run, the boilerplate code to do it, everything has an impact. The engine optimizes to each situation and the results, well, are garbage in the end.

Read this: https://medium.com/cacher-app/how-js-benchmarks-lie-fa35fa989ee0

Or the discussion on: [Which JS benchmark site is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612083/which-js-benchmark-site-is-correct)

When I come into an issue with my code, I test it in that exact context as this is where it will actually need to go fast. This means that 1 solution does not fit all, many, but not all.