# How to get all matches properties from JSON payload in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, html-lists

I'm new and learning `JSON` but I have been having an issue with displaying some `API` results:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    enText = data.data.count;
    arText = data.data.matches.text;
    document.getElementById('verseText').innerHTML = 'Matches: '+enText+'';
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = arText;
})
```

`enText` works fine but how do I list the text of all the matches using `JSON` (above) into an `HTML` list
assuming this is the endpoint: http://api.alquran.cloud/v1/search/abraham/all/en

Comment: Can you please describe that actually which result you want? I mean sample output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your API response `matches` is an array of object. So you need to iterate the loop to access the `text` value

```
$.getJSON("http://api.alquran.cloud/v1/search/abraham/all/en", function (data) {
    enText = data.data.count;
    arText = data.data.matches;

    var li= '';
    for (const x of arText) {
        li+='<li>'+x.text+' <span class="surah">'+x.surah.name+'</span></li>';

    }

    document.getElementById('verseText').innerHTML = 'Matches: ' + enText + '';
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = li;
})
```

Otherwise if you want a single data, get it using index value. Like below code

```
arText = data.data.matches[0].text;
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = arText;
```

Comment: How would I put each result in an li tag?

Comment: Thanks so much! I would upvote but I dont have any points

Comment: No worries. But you can accept my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Comment: Oh, when I accepted an answer, I have enough points to upvote, lol

Comment: What if I wanted to get the surah name.

Comment: match>surah>name and put those right after the text

Answer (score 1):

`matches` is a `JSON Array`. You need to iterate over elements and grab `text` property. Also, remember to declare variables in handler function with `const`, `let` or `var`.

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    const enText = data.data.count;
    const arText = data.data.matches
                       .map(m => `<li>${m.text}</li>`)
                       .join("");
    document.getElementById('verseText').innerHTML = 'Matches: '+enText+'';
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = arText;
})
```

Comment: @mkHun, good point. Of course we need to take under consideration one side effect: map function creates extra array with transformed elements. After that we need to iterate it again to join all elements to a String variable. Your for-of solution is definitely faster. In case user would like to provide some filter function or do more sophisticated modification on input array this approach allows easier way to implement it. Also, `String` concat is faster: [Array Join vs String Concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296594/array-join-vs-string-concat). But it depends from implementation.