# How to generate ul li from a nested array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, recursion, html-lists

I have the following code below and trying to find a way to generate `<ul>` and `<li>` to output an unordered list via Javascript.

**Question(s):**

1. How can I parse the following array to generate a nested unordered list html?
2. If I were to use recursion, how would I recursively iterate through all nested children to print a nested unordered list?

**What I tried that didn't work**

```
const data = [
    {
        name: '125313-7j',
    },
    {
        name: '584996-s7',
        _children: [
            {
                name: '747773-jw',
            },
            {
                name: '377526-zg',
                _children: [
                    {
                        name: '955330-wp',
                    },
                    {
                        name: '343693-9x',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                name: '638483-y2'
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: '306979-mx'
    },
    {
        name: '066195-o1',
        _children: [],
    },
];

$(function() {
let innerHtml = '<ul>';
data.forEach( item => {
  innerHTML += '<li>' + '<div>' + item.name + '</div>';
    if(item._children) {
      // ***ISSUE***  this doesn't print all the children so i cannot recursively get all the children
       console.log('children', item._children);
    }
});

innerHtml += '</ul>';
});
```

**Expected output**

```
<ul>
  <li> <div>Name1</div>
     <ul>
        <li><div>Name2</div>
         .... continue the next unordered list until all children have been displayed ...
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, the recursive solution seems more intuitive to me. Let me share my insights for approaching this:

```bash
# Pseudocode

# generateList(items)
#   1. init: html<String> with opening "<ul>" tag. 
#            Can also use array. See References section

#   2. for item in items
#       2.1. html += "<li><div>", item.name, "</div>"
#       2.2. if item has _children and the length of _children is greater than 0
#            2.2.1. html += result of calling generateNestedList recursively with item._children
#       2.3. html += closing "<\li>"

#   3. html += closing "</ul>"

#   4. return html.
# end function
```

```js
const data = [{
    name: '125313-7j',
  },
  {
    name: '584996-s7',
    _children: [{
        name: '747773-jw',
      },
      {
        name: '377526-zg',
        _children: [{
            name: '955330-wp',
          },
          {
            name: '343693-9x',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: '638483-y2'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: '306979-mx'
  },
  {
    name: '066195-o1',
    _children: [],
  },
];

function generateList(items) {
  let html = '<ul>';

  items.forEach((item) => {
    html += '<li><div>' + item.name + '</div>';
    if (item._children?.length > 0) {
      html += generateList(item._children);
    }
    html += '</li>';
  });

  html += '</ul>';
  return html;
}

const innerHtml = generateList(data);
// console.log(innerHtml);
document.getElementById("list-container").innerHTML = innerHtml;
```

```html
<div id="list-container"></div>
```

---

##### References:

1. [Array Join vs String Concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296594/array-join-vs-string-concat#:%7E:text=For%20small%20number%20of%20iteration,in%20both%20chrome%20and%20firefox.)
2. [Optional Chaining(`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 2):

As you seem to be using jQuery, here is a solution using jQuery style, producing the object structure, ready to inject in the HTML document:

```js
function createHtml(data) {
    return $("<ul>").append(
        (data ?? []).map(({ name, _children }) =>
            $("<li>").append(
                $("<div>").text(name),
                data?.length ? createHtml(_children) : []
            )
        )
    );
}

const data = [{name: '125313-7j',},{name: '584996-s7',_children: [{name: '747773-jw',},{name: '377526-zg',_children: [{name: '955330-wp',},{name: '343693-9x',},],},{name: '638483-y2'},],},{name: '306979-mx'},{name: '066195-o1',_children: [],},];
const $ul = createHtml(data);
$("#container").append($ul);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

An advantage of setting the text with `text()`, is that you'll not have issues if the item's name has character sequences that could be misinterpreted as HTML, such as `<` or `&` in combination with other characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by your two questions.  Below is a version which converts your object structure into the sort of nested list structure you're looking for.

Your code will not work without one big change.  You need to make a function out of the body and *call* that function in your `*** ISSUE ***` block.

My version uses [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#string_interpolation) instead of concatenation, but expresses much the same logic.  Note the separation of concerns.  `toList` creates an HTML string.  It's left to the calling code to insert that into the document.

```js
const toList = (xs) => `<ul>${xs.map (x => `<li><div>${x.name}</div>${
  '_children' in x && x._children.length > 0 ? toList(x._children) : ``
}</li>`).join('')}</ul>`

const data = [{name: "125313-7j"}, {name: "584996-s7", _children: [{name: "747773-jw"}, {name: "377526-zg", _children: [{name: "955330-wp"}, {name: "343693-9x"}]}, {name: "638483-y2"}]}, {name: "306979-mx"}, {name: "066195-o1", _children: []}]

const html = toList(data)
console.log(html)
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = html
```

```html
<div id="content" />
```

We don't try to format the HTML nicely with line breaks and indentation.  We could add that, but for HTML it's usually an unnecessary complexity.  However, if we were trying to create a nested, indented plain text list, we might add a depth (here `d`) parameter, which we increment on each recursive level, and use to set indentation level:

```js
const toText = (xs, d = 0) => xs.map (x => '    '.repeat(d) + x.name +
  ('_children' in x && x._children.length > 0 ? '\n' + toText(x._children, d + 1) : '')
).join('\n')

const data = [{name: "125313-7j"}, {name: "584996-s7", _children: [{name: "747773-jw"}, {name: "377526-zg", _children: [{name: "955330-wp"}, {name: "343693-9x"}]}, {name: "638483-y2"}]}, {name: "306979-mx"}, {name: "066195-o1", _children: []}]

console.log(toText(data))
```